# when is it safe to NOT use parametised query

Tags: parameterized-query

I know this is a loaded question but I want to understand the theory here.

I've tried googling and checking SO for this and i DO understand the SQL injection threat.

My question is:  Do you ALWAYS needs parametised queries?

eg.

If I have a user input box to search for "pxName"
I have a string:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblPeople WHERE fName = '" & pxName & "'"
```

I completely see the risk here, we are open to attack because the user has the power to insert what they want into the input box.

If however I have a variable that I have created.

eg.
Created new record via an ADODB recordset.
Obtained new PK

run query:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblPeople WHERE personID = " & NewPrimaryKey
```

Is this a threat??  As in, should this be parametised as parametised queries are "what you do" or am I actually at risk of SQL injection even though there is no place for a user to even input their dodgy strings to perform an attack?

The main fact is I have created an access app just for me to use and now a bunch of friends with similar businesses are keen to try it.  It isn't using Parametisation at all at the moment however of maybe 50 query strings in the VBA, there are only 2 with actual user input boxes, the rest are reports and self generated variable queries like the one above.

Thanks!

Comment: Any time the SQL uses user input, that input should be parameterized. Period. No exceptions. If the SQL doesn't include any chance of using user input data, you're fine.

Comment: But ask yourself this: with a mix of queries using non-parameterisation and parameterisation, will you be able to notice when a user-input slips through the net?

Comment: thanks guys.  The AIM is to get all parametised for the very reason @AndyJames has mentioned.  KenWhite answered the question, it just confirmed what I suspected but I guess wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding some hackable code aspect!